# JointJS needs Jquery as its dependency. Unfortunately, Jquery is breaking my ExtJS application. Any workaround?

Tags: jquery, extjs, jointjs

I noticed that JointJS has JQuery as its dependency. My application is built on ExtJS v3. Its pretty old app. When I try to include a  tag with Jquery v3.5.1 cdn location to it, I notice that it breaks my ExtJS code somewhere.

Is there anyway I can include the JQuery for JointJS to work without breaking my ExtJS application?

Currently, this is what I am trying.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.0/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.3.1/joint.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't have experience with this old version, but if you have a part beginning with `"js": [` in your `app.json` file, you can try adding a new element to this array like `{"path": "https:/...."}`.

Answer (score 1):

It could help us if you post your non-working complete code.

Currently, there seem to have dependencies between JointJS and jQuery, cf https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/127

For preventing conflicts between jQuery and other libraries such as Extjs, a common way is to replace $() by jQuery().

You also have the "radical" way to encapsulate your JointJS app in an "iframe" inside your Extjs app. It's not a very clean solution, but it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the code for reference. I did have look into JointJS and Jquery dependency. The latest JointJS has references to Jquery as $. What I found was, if I use jquery.noConflict() and then use jquery instead of $ in JointJS, things work.